# How to enable Java Advanced Imaging in Geoserver for Mac OS?

Tags: geoserver, jai

I am trying to enable the JAI in Geoserver for my raster processing. I checked JAI and Image I/O is only available for Linux and Windows. Also, JAI comes pre shipped with every copy of Mac OS. I am using Mac OS, but my Geoserver shows that JAI is false. Why is it false? How can I enable JAI on Geoserver?

The following is the screenshot of my Geoserver:

[image]

Comment: As described in http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/java.html, there is  **No native JAI** for MacOS, as shown in your config. You get Java-based JAI (as shown in your config - see max memory, tile threads, etc) from GeoServer.

Comment: So, are you saying that it is enabled, but it will show JAI to be false in Mac OS ?

Comment: I see that's what confusing me as well

Comment: On windows and Linux there are two types of JAI, one in java and one in C (or some other compiled language) with the 2nd (native) one being faster. On a Mac there is only a Java one because Apple didn't supply a native one so you can not turn native support on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't showing that JAI is not available, but rather than *Native JAI* (i.e. JAI using native code, rather than using pure Java) is not available. JAI is available (not least because GeoServer provides it), as shown by the following entries - `JAI Maximum Memory`, `Number of JAI Tile Threads` and so on.

As described in [the manual](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/java.html), there is no native JAI for MacOS. If you need native JAI for some performance reason, you'll need to use a different environment.